# Retrieving row indices of a pandas dataframe based on search criteria encoded as a dictionary {column:value}?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to search a dataframe based on criteria supplied as a dictionary of the type {column:value}.

For example this dataframe along with the search dictionary should produce as a query result '0' (the index of the dataframe row which satisfies the search criteria.

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4], 'col2': [2,3,4,5]}, index = [0,1,2,3])

search = {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge data (inner by default) with the criteria as a `DataFrame`:

```
answer = test.merge(pd.Series(search).to_frame().T).index
```

If we have several cases, it's even easier:

```
search = {'col1': [1, 3], 'col2': [2, 4]}
answer = test.merge(pd.DataFrame(search)).index
```

or as in this case with a list of criteria:

```
criteria = [
    {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2},
    {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}
]

search = pd.DataFrame(criteria)

test.merge(search)
```

[pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. I'm exporting the entire final filtered df based on search dictionary. But if you want just index values, put `final_filtered_df.index`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4], 'col2': [2,3,4,5]}, index = [0,1,2,3])
search = {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}

# Filter columns using filter function
filtered_columns = df.filter(items=search.keys())

# Filter rows based on the search dictionary values
final_filtered_df = filtered_columns[filtered_columns.isin(search.values()).all(axis=1)]

print(final_filtered_df)

col1  col2
0     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes that the names in `search` match all the columns in the dataframe.

[image]

The code takes each row at a time (`axis=1`), and tests all the columns for that row against the supplied dict. If all the tests are `True` for that row (`all(...)`), `True` is returned for that row, or `False` otherwise.

```py
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4], 'col2': [2,3,4,5]}, index = [0,1,2,3])

search = {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}

meets_condition = test.apply(
    lambda row: True if all([search[colname] == row[colname] for colname in search]) else False,
    axis=1
)

#Indices were condition is met
indices_where_met = test.index[meets_condition].values
print('Condition met at indices:', indices_where_met)

#The filtered table
test.loc[meets_condition]
```